# Wrong person's photo in my Google image search

Tags: seo, google, google-search, google-image-search, image-search

Suppose my name is John Doe. I search google with "John Doe". Then in the image search result I find an image of another person. How can I remove this image from the search results?

Best regards,

John Doe

Comment: Is your name so unique that there are no others on the planet?? This does happen, but is extremely rare.

Comment: You have to be more popular than John Doe... and if you're talking about Google SERP from your own search trying something like `"John Doe" -"Harry Chestnut"` might do it.

Comment: Questions here are required to be about a [website under your control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you can edit this to explain how it relates to your website, then it will be added back to the review queue to be considered for reopening.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you don't understand how google image search works.  Like regular google searches it will return all results for the search word/phrase.  So unless your name or search is unique there will be multiple results.

If you are searching for your image by name there are a few things you ought be aware of.

1. Is there actually an image with your name attached to it via the file name or a caption or context?
2. There may be hundreds of John Doe's out there all going "hey, that's not me".
3. The site with your image may not have been indexed yet
4. No search engine is perfect.

And as for removing that image, somewhere another John Doe would be saying "Hey, what happened to my image?".

Once upon a time there was a game to try to do a google search for a two word phrase and get a unique result.  I think that would be impossible nowadays.